# How to call a php file with parameters on click of a button?

Tags: php, html

I have the following code in a file called send_payment.php that I have been given. It sends some parameters to a bank payment page, I presume when a form has been submitted somewhere.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad()
        {
            document.frmInput.submit();
        }   
    </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="onLoad();">
<form name="frmInput" id="frmInput" 
action="https://tmbepgw.tmbbank.com/TMBPayment/Payment.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id=MERID name=MERID value="000001110801149">
    <input type="hidden" id=TERMINALID name=TERMINALID value="78000113">
    <input type="hidden" id=AMOUNT name=amount value="000000000000">
    <input type="hidden" id=BACKENDURL name=BackendUrl value="">
    <input type="hidden" id=RESPONSEURL name=ResponseUrl value="http://www.nibh.com/html">
    <input type="hidden" id=MERCHANTDATA name=merchantdata value="NIBH">
    <input type="hidden" id=INVOICENO name=INVOICENO value="090517153914">
    <input type="hidden" id=CURRENCYCODE name=CURRENCYCODE value="764">
    <input type="hidden" id=VERSION name=VERSION value="1.0">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the code from a form submission on my site, that contains an href upon click of a button:

```
<a class="button" href="#">Make Payment</a>
```

In that code I have access to fields from the form like $AMOUNT etc... for the send_payment.php.

But, am stuck. I want to make the same call as in the .php file when the user clicks submit.

1. How do I call the same code as in send_payment.php file when my button is clicked?
2. I just want to send the same variables in the 'action' of the send_payment page
3. Is it best to call a php file to do this - if so any guides on how to send parameters to a php file and then call that URL:

   "https://tmbepgw.tmbbank.com/TMBPayment/Payment.aspx" method="post"

With the variables I have at that time? (e.g. $amount etc...)

Thanks.

Comment: you should be looking for `$_POST['amount']`

Comment: ...or `$_POST['AMOUNT']` (keys in an array are case sensitive). I would recommend you to wrap your id's and name's in quotes. it will work either way, but it's more "correct" to wrap all argument values in quotes.

Comment: First how are you submitting the form? Preceded button, href, submit button.

Comment: I dont know if I understand your question. Your form submit the data to "...Payment.aspx", but you want to send the data to another file too, the "...send_payment.php", correct? In other words, receive the form data in two files. If it is right, i suggested you to use ajax. Do you know how to work with ajax? If no, I can explain.

Comment: too many questions; none accepted.

Comment: Dr Somar, I need to submit the data to ..Payment.aspx indeed. On click of my 'Make Payment' button, I need to send the variables $amount etc... to the .aspx file. Currently, that call is made in the send_payment.php file from some legacy code that had a form. I want to just replicate this functionality. 1. how to send the variables to a .php file on click of the 'Make Payment' button?   Ok - I can get the variables from the $_POST array the the PHP, but then 2. how do I make a call (in PHP) to the .aspx with the variables? I.e. take that functionality from the current HTML and put in php call?

Comment: Jose Marques: I have a submit button that currently calls an href, but am not sure how to call .php file on click of button, and in the PHP file, not sure how to make PHP call to the .aspx file with all the variables passed to the PHP file (which I now understand I can get from $_POST[] )

Comment: @wanwu The `action` attribute in the `form` tag calls to ONE file, not two like you want. I suggest you to use AJAX. Keep the `action` attribute blank. In javascript, create an action CLICK in the payment button. Get the input values and send via AJAX POST to TWO files, the ASPX and the PHP. Do you use jQuery in your site? I can write a code to you if you use jQuery.

Comment: @DR.somar To simplify what I need: I want just a PHP function that calls the .aspx page with the variables - to duplicate what is in send_payment.php. I just need to know how to make that function. Then I can call a .php file from the action command, and pass in the variables as query strings ?. The function in the .php file will then pick these up, and make the POST call to .aspx file. Make sense? But not sure how to make this php function.

Answer (score 0):

Using only PHP, to send the POST to TWO files, you need to use CURL.
Do this:

1) Set the `action` attribute in the `form tag` pointing the PHP file (`send_payment.php`)

2) In the file `send_payment.php`, you will need to send the $_POST variables to the `.aspx` file using CURL, like that:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://tmbepgw.tmbbank.com/TMBPayment/Payment.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ( $server_output ){
    // true
} else {
    //false
}
```

This is a most simple way to send a POST using CURL. The most host servers have the CURL enabled. But check with your host if is really enable. Perhaps the host has an example to use the CURL in your server. But CURL has no mistery.

You can put this code in a function, like that:

```
function send_payment_curl( $post, $to_url ){
     $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$to_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ( $server_output ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your file `send_payment.php`, just call the function:

```
$r = send_payment_curl( $_POST, "https://tmbepgw.tmbbank.com/TMBPayment/Payment.aspx" );

if ( $r ){
    // it works!
} else {
    // there's a problem with the CURL. Please check the code
}
```

I hope it help you!

Comment: @Dr.somer, thanks so much  It have the code calling fine now from the button. But as per screen shot ( https://postimg.org/image/i7r35bb2h/ ), I am struggling with the $_POST variables. I want to match the same call with all same variables as in original call in the send_payment.php. How do I replicate all those variables into the $post variable?  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($_POST)); (( I presume this is typo and should be $post as that is what is passed into this function )).  How variables like : add <input type="hidden" id=MERID name=MERID value="000001110801149">

Comment: @Dr.somer I need just all these variables send in the $post array? `<form name="frmInput" id="frmInput" 
action="https://tmbepgw.tmbbank.com/TMBPayment/Payment.aspx" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id=MERID name=MERID value="000001110801149">
    <input type="hidden" id=TERMINALID name=TERMINALID value="78000113">
    <input type="hidden" id=AMOUNT name=amount value="000000000000">
    <input type="hidden" id=BACKENDURL name=BackendUrl value="">
    <input type="hidden" id=RESPONSEURL name=ResponseUrl value="http://www.nibh.com/html">' etc.. etc..`

Comment: @wanwu When you send a POST to a PHP file indicated in the `form action` attribute, the `$_POST` variable is created automatically. This GLOBAL variable is an array containing all fields in your form. Example: The `input` with `name=MERID` and `value=000001110801149` will be received in the PHP file like that: `$_POST['MERID'] = 000001110801149`. Is the same with ALL fields. The field attribute name will be the associative key in the `$_POST` array. Then, if you send the $_POST variable in the CURL, you are sending the original call. [Explanation](https://postimg.org/image/90jwb5wgh/)